# Install different versions of nuget packages inside one solution file with two projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

I have two .csproj projects named A and B under one solution file (.sln),  I need to install a custom nuget package of version 1.0 in A and 2,0 in B.  Is that possible?  I have tried to install-package   but it updates the solution. Both of them are now updated to 2.0.

Comment: use console for install package per project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the console instead the manager window,

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 6.0.8
```

in the other project

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 5.0.3
```